# IE stuck when data loads in radcombobox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik

I have an unexpected error in my live project and I don't understand what is the reason behind it. I am using *Telerik* controls in my project.

When I select "All" option and click on button then other radcombobox loads according to these selected values and here the issue comes. When I select "All" then processing is stuck in between and error message is displayed on the screen. This issue occurs only in IE browser.

> Error: xyz.com is not responding

Following is the version of IE:

[image]

Simple functionality is running in behind the code. It has more than 50,000+ data in database.

HTML code:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl1" Filter="StartsWith" DropDownWidth="300px" MaxHeight="200px" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
          <telerik:RadButton ID="btnApply1" Text="Apply" Style="vertical-align: middle !important" OnClick="btnApply1_Click" runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 75%;">
          <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl2" Filter="StartsWith" DropDownWidth="300px" MaxHeight="200px" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

C# code:

```
protected void btnApply1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     try
     {
           //code for fill next filter ddl2 
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
       
     }
   }
```

Comment: [How to ask ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you reproduce this in a stand alone minimal project? May we have a code sample to test it ? I can not reproduce this on 11.713 IE but its not a surprise as every use full information is missing( ajax ? client event or js on the combo? a detail trace of what is happening using F12?) Are you able to reproduce it with an other IE on a other computer?

Comment: @PierreLebon, please check the "update 1".

Comment: Suonds like you have a really big loop...

Comment: You need to debug your code behind in your asp.net modules. Run from VS in Debug mode.